# Does iter built in function sort the collection elements whenever possible?

Tags: python

[`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) generates an ordered collection from the unordered set as below. Is this sorted result a guaranteed behaviour of Python 3?

```
>>> x = {1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 6}
>>> y = iter(x)
>>> list(y)
[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]      # <--- Sorted
```

Comment: Sets are unordered. Try `print(list({1000, 1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 6}))` Also, there isn't any mention in the documentation for `iter()` that it creates *ordered* collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Nothing is defined about the iteration order of sets (whether by `iter(set)` or `for e in set:` or ...).

Try it on a set of strings instead, and you'll probably find that the order changes across runs.

What you're seeing is an indirect consequence of how `hash(int)` happens to be computed, and its interaction with how sets happen to be implemented today, under CPython.

Under a recent PyPy, it's different:

```
Python 3.10.12 (af44d0b8114cb82c40a07bb9ee9c1ca8a1b3688c, Jun 15 2023, 15:42:22)
[PyPy 7.3.12 with MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
...
>>>> x = {1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 6}
>>>> y = iter(x)
>>>> list(y)
[1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 6]
```

So the original order happened to be retained - which isn't guaranteed either.